# How to solve too many input arguments

Tags: matlab, fitness

I've tried to add angle ratio function into my fitness evaluation function. When i've run the code, the error shows "Too many input arguments" for line code: tmp_angle = angle(points(j-1, :), points(j, :), points(j+1, :));

Below is the code for the fitness evaluation function:

```
function fitness = fitness_evaluation(M, task, N, pop)

   % fitness: the fitness of the population
   % M: the number of the tasks
   % task: the tasks of mobile users
   % N: the number of UAVs
   % pop: the population

   H = 100;   % the altitude of each UAV
   theta = pi / 4;   % the beamwidth of each directional antenna
   k1 = 1e-27;   % the effective switched capacitance
   k2 = 1e-28;   % the effective switched capacitance
   v = 3;   % the positive constant
   B = 1e6;   % the channel bandwidth
   P = 1;   % the transmission power of each mobile device
   B0 = 1.42e-4;   % the channel power gain at the reference distance
   G0 = 2.2846;   % the positive constant
   N0 = 1e-20;   % the noise power spectrum density
   P0 = 1000;   % the hover power of each UAV
   T_max = 1;   % the maximum time used to complete each task

   F = reshape(task(2 * M + 1 : 3 * M)' * ones(1, N), 1, M * N);
   D = reshape(task(3 * M + 1 : end)' * ones(1, N), 1, M * N);

   x = reshape(task(1 : M)' * ones(1, N), 1, M * N);
   y = reshape(task(M + 1 : 2 * M)' * ones(1, N), 1, M * N);
   X = reshape(ones(M, 1) * pop(1 : N), 1, M * N);
   Y = reshape(ones(M, 1) * pop(N + 1 : 2 * N), 1, M * N);

   a = pop(2 * N + 1 : 2 * N + M * (N + 1));
   f = pop(2 * N + M * (N + 1) + 1 : end);

   r = B * log2(1 + P * B0 * G0 ./ (N0 * B * theta ^ 2 * (H ^ 2 + (x - X) .^ 2 + (y - Y) .^ 2)));

   % Calculate the fitness of the population and the number of uncompleted tasks
   f0 = sum(a(1 : M) * k1 .* f(1 : M) .^ (v - 1) .* F(1 : M)) + sum(a(M + 1 : end) * k2 .* f(M + 1 : end) .^ (v - 1) .* F) + sum(a(M + 1 : end) * P .* D ./ r) + N * P0 * T_max;
   g = M - sum(a); % number of uncompleted tasks

   % Calculate angle ratio
   angle_ratio_value = angle_ratio(pop);

   % Add angle ratio to the fitness evaluation result
   fitness = -[f0, g, f0 + g * 1e20, angle_ratio_value];

end

% Calculate angle ratio
function result = angle_ratio(pop)
   pi_val = pi;
   ratio = zeros(size(pop, 1), 1);
   for i = 1:size(pop, 1)
       path = pop(i, :);
       points = path;
       n = length(points);
       perfect_angle = (n - 2) * pi_val / n;
       points = [points(end, :); points; points(1, :)];
       suma = 0;
       for j = 2:n+1
           tmp_angle = angle(points(j-1, :), points(j, :), points(j+1, :));
           if (tmp_angle > pi_val)
               tmp_angle = pi_val - tmp_angle;
           end
           suma = suma + abs((tmp_angle - pi_val) / pi_val);
       end
       ratio(i) = 1 - suma / n;
   end
   result = sum(ratio) / size(pop, 1);
end
```

Comment: MATLAB's `angle` function returns the phase angle of a complex number (or array of complex numbers). https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html . It accepts only a single input. I don't think it is computing what you want here.